# How to cat a file in this OS module example

Tags: python

I need to cat a file inside the OS module of python.

What I'm trying to do is what I have accomplished in Perl. Please note the `cat /tmp/illinois.txt`

```
my $cmd = `$ENV{BB} $ENV{BBDISP} "status $host.$test $COLOR \`date\` 
\`cat /tmp/illinois.txt\`"`;
```

I would like to do the same thing in python.

```
cmd = "{BB} {BBDISP} \"status {NODE}.{TEST} {COLOR} {NOW}\n {MSG}\n\"".format(
TEST = "gov-affairs-MemoryUtilization",
BB = os.environ["BB"],
BBDISP = os.environ["BBDISP"],
COLOR = COLOR,
NOW = datetime.datetime.now(),
MSG=`cat /tmp/illinois.txt\`,
NODE="xxxxx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run commands from your script:

```
subprocess.run(cmd.split())
```

The `run()` function also takes parameters like `shell=True` if you want to keep the environment variables or `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` if you want to retreive the output of the command. 
Honestly, just take a look at the docs ;)
EDIT: as Alan mentionned, the `shell=True` option is often considered not desirable, as you cannot be sure which shell is used by the system. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

Comment: I'd suggest you add that using `shell=True` is considered to be less desirable.

Comment: The subprocess.run() function only exists in Python 3.5 and newer.